# While uploading an excel file, Getting Oledb Exception -Too many fields defined?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, file-upload, export-to-excel

I am uploading an Excel having 5 sheets. While uploading i am getting the error " TOO MANY FIELDS DEFINED "

```
public DataSet ExportQCCheckData(string filepath)
{
    string path = filepath;
    OleDbConnection con;
    System.Data.DataTable dt = null;
    //Connection string for oledb
    string conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + path + "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;'";
    con = new OleDbConnection(conn);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        //get the sheet name in to a table

        dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        String[] excelsheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;
        //using foreach get the sheet name in a string array called excelsheets[]
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            excelsheets[i] = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            i++;
        }
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int cnt = 0;
        foreach (string temp in excelsheets)
        {
            if (temp == "BASIC$" || temp == "SHORT$" || temp == "CLASS$" || temp == "MEMO$" || temp == "SOURCE$")
            {
                string query = "select * from [" + temp + "]";
                OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
                adp.Fill(ds, temp);
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        if (cnt != 5)
        {
            ds = null;
        }
        return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.Message);
        DataSet ds = null;
        return ds;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the first line in your excel sheet contain header names. If so include HDR=Yes; in you connection string to indicate that the first line is a header row

Comment: I saw similar type of Question.. but that does not solve my problem

Comment: yeah, first line indicates header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error belongs to number of fields on excel sheet kindly add excel sheet. you need to verify that excel sheet doesn't contain a lot of columns

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the excel contains many columns . so what i do it means, just select all the empty cells

> Control -

Then i upload the excel sheet, it uploaded.